# C# Linq GroupBy - With Specific criteria

Tags: c#, linq

I have the below table which I want to group ,

```
Id   NameId   ValueId
1       1       4
1       10      18
1       9       15

2       1       4
2       10      17
2       9       0

3       1       5
3       9       16
3       10      18

4       1       5
4       10      18
4       9       16

5       1       4
5       10      17
5       9       0
```

The result should be grouped with Id having similar ValueId for all the corresponding NameId

Output

```
GroupId                                      Id          ValueId
fed1afcc-a778-48ef-9ee5-4b70886ce67c          1           4,18,15
a31055df-2e4e-472e-9301-e0e0a4e99f1e          2,5         4,17,0
8b9b3dca-4ce0-4cae-a870-1d1026bd608a          3,4         5,18,16
```

I actually don't need them concatenated, it is just a representation of how the output should be grouped.

I have done a working implementation using a nested for loop, which compare each entity to the subsequent entity and does a check for all the values. Am I over doing something which can be simply achieved in Linq?

Or how can this be done in Linq ?

A minimal version of my current code

```
  var tableResult = _repository.GetData().OrderBy(x =>x.NameId).ToList();
  var ids = tableResult.Select(x => x.id).Distinct().ToList();
  var listOfProductGroup = new List<ProductGroup>();
  for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count; i++)
  {   
       var currentId = ids[i];
       var currentEntity = tableResult.Where(x => x.id == currentId).ToList();
       var productGroup = new ProductGroup(Guid.NewGuid(), currentProductId);

      for (int j = i + 1; j < ids.Count; j++)
      {
         var subsequentId = ids[j];
         var subsequentEntity = tableResult.Where(x => x.id == subsequentId ).ToList();
         //This is my extension method which does the comparison
         if(currentEntity.EqualsAll(subsequentEntity))
         {
            productGroup.Id.Add(subsequentId );
            //am removing the product to avoid extra loop
            ids.RemoveAt(j);
            //adjust the index to match the removed product
            j = j - 1;
         }
      }
  }
  listOfProductGroup.Add(productGroup);


public class ProductGroup
{

    public ProductGroup(Guid groupId, int id)
    {
        GroupId= groupId;
        Id= new List<int>()
        {
            id
        };
    }
    public Guid GroupId{ get; set; }
    public IList<int> Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your posted code does generate grouped-data as its output, it just returns `true` - I don't see how it relates to the example data you've given. Additionally I don't see what the relationship is between `Id`, `GroupId`, `NameId` and `ValueId`. Your code also seems to depend on the input being sorted in a particular way, but your existing query does not ensure any specific ordering. *Never* rely on the ordering returned from querying a table.

Comment: Like I have said, it is just a minimal version. I'll be creating a new entity with-in the if block.
before doing the loop, I sort the `tableResult` by `NameId`

`GroupId` is just an auto-increment for the groups being created.

`Id` denotes a product which has `Name` and `Value` attributes

Comment: Hello can you give an example code so that we can test solutions on? especially the class with Id, NameId and ValueId?

Comment: I have updated the source code, can you let me know if this is sufficient ? @Dai ,haytam

Comment: I assume that  4,8,15 should be  4,18,15 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
class DictionaryComparer : IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<int, int>>
{
    public bool Equals(Dictionary<int, int> x, Dictionary<int, int> y)
    {
        return x.Count == y.Count && !x.Except(y).Any();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Dictionary<int, int> obj)
    {
        int hash = 0;
        foreach (var kvp in obj.OrderBy(x => x.Key))
        {
            hash = hash ^ EqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<int, int>>.Default.GetHashCode(kvp);
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
class Thing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int NameId { get; set; }
    public int ValueId { get; set; }

    public Thing(int id, int nameId, int valueId)
    {
        Id = id;
        NameId = nameId;
        ValueId = valueId;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new Thing[]
        {
            new Thing(1,       1,       4),
            new Thing(1,       10,      18),
            new Thing(1,       9,       15),
            new Thing(2,       1,       4),
            new Thing(2,       10,      17),
            new Thing(2,       9,       0),
            new Thing(3,       1,       5),
            new Thing(3,       9,       16),
            new Thing(3,       10,      18),
            new Thing(4,       1,       5),
            new Thing(4,       10,      18),
            new Thing(4,       9,       16),
            new Thing(5,       1,       4),
            new Thing(5,       10,      17),
            new Thing(5,       9,       0),
        };

        var @as = data.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
            .Select(x => new {Id = x.Key, Data = x.ToDictionary(t => t.NameId, t => t.ValueId)})
            .GroupBy(x => x.Data, x => x.Id, new DictionaryComparer());

        foreach (var a in @as)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", string.Join(",", a), string.Join(",", a.Key.Values));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated to an XOR approach instead.

Comment: Thanks, Worked like a charm!!